# Can any function be written as a linear combination of only sines?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

In the fourier transform sines and cosines are used to form an orthogonal basis. But since $\sin x$, $\sin 2x$, $\sin3x$ are already orthogonal, why do we even need the cosine terms to represent a function? The same applies for cosines, why do we need sines? If $\sin nx$ form an orthogonal basis, can't any vector (in this case function) be represented as a linear combination of sines only?

Comment: What interval do you want to represent functions on?

Comment: all real numbers

Comment: Then sines and cosines are *not orthogonal* with standard scalar product: $\langle f, g\rangle = \int fg dx$ because they are not even integrable

Comment: How does the fourier transform then work if it goes from minus to plus infinity?

Comment: This is not Fourier Transform but Fourier Series. You cannot use the sines to represent $\cos{(x)}$, as one example

Comment: The fourier transform calculates the dot product of a function and a sind and cosine function from negative to positive infinity

Comment: Then try to approximate a function that is non-zero at $x=0$ using only sines

Comment: You cant do that for every function. Even functions can be represented with purely cosines and odd with purely sines. Every other function is a mixture of the two. My original question is why is this a case? In other words why is the basis of sines not complete and how do we know when a basis is complete so it can represent an infinite vector/function?